# How to handle the ActionAppNotificationSettings?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, notifications, settings

I have a xamarin app and wont to open a specific settings page.

Settings -> Apps -> Special app access -> Notification access

I found out about the intent, and for normal settings, it looks like this:

```
var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionNotificationListenerSettings);
// ActionAppNotificationSettings  <-- does not work
// ActionManageOverlayPermission  <-- does not work 
// ActionNotificationListenerSettings  <-- does not work
// ActionApplicationDetailsSettings <-- works
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromParts("package", Application.Context.PackageName, null);
intent.SetData(uri);
Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

I only can open the normal Settings page, with ActionApplicationDetailsSettings
But I GUESS that the ActionNotificationListenerSettings should open my desired location (I don't know exactly if it does indeed open this: Settings -> Apps -> Special app access -> Notification access)

But with the ActionNotificationListenerSettings, the app throws this error:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS
```

Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ActionAppNotificationSettings` instead of `ActionNotificationListenerSettings`. Here is the code example:

```
public void goToSetting()
{

    //startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));

    var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionAppNotificationSettings);

    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    intent.PutExtra(Android.Provider.Settings.ExtraAppPackage, Application.Context.PackageName);
    intent.PutExtra(Android.Provider.Settings.ExtraChannelId, Application.Context.ApplicationInfo.Uid);

    StartActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: First of, thank you for your response, but I have the same problem as mentioned above, the error looks like this: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS flg=0x10000000 (has extras)

Comment: Here is my test sample, please check: [sample](https://github.com/XfHua/Android-specific-setting-sample).

Comment: This is very simmilar to what I Have, but it still throws the error. Do you think, that it is possible that my set-top box simply does not have the required handler to open that specific intent?

Comment: Does my sample work on your side? Can you please share me your code sample which can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I downloaded your project, and run it, its the same error: android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: 'No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS flg=0x10000000 (has extras) }'

Comment: What's the API level of your emulator?

Comment: It is: 28 SDK, 21 NDK

Comment: Can you please try another emulator? I test it on my side with 29/28 SDK, and it both works well.

Comment: I just tried your code on another box, and it worked...so it's definitly a local problem on the first box that does not handle the intent well....Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: @Elydasian I run to this issues with custom device and tv boxes.
For these device that have "No Activity found to handle", does it mean they can't show notifications?

Comment: @uDevel, every box has the ability to show notifications, your "No Activity found to handle" indicates that you do not send it as it's supposed to be sent, so I would look on that. Also, I am out from that project, and I wont be able to help you on that anymore